# Event broadcast is not working when queueis use in our project

Tags: laravel-5, pusher

I was broadcasting my event with help of pusher,it's worked fine but when i used queue implementation then pusher haven't receive any broadcast or may be event is not broadcasting.I'm not understand what the issue is.Code is given below please help me

Controller function

```
public function index()
{       $this->user_id=2;
        Event::fire(new UpdateDeviceStatus($this->user_id));
}
```

Event file

```
class UpdateDeviceStatus extends Event implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public $devices;
    public function __construct($id)
    {
        $this->devices=Device::with('units')->where('user_id',$id)->get();
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should be broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return ['update-status'];
    }
}
```

js file

```
Pusher.logToConsole = true;

    var pusher = new Pusher('key', {
        encrypted: true
    });
        var channel = pusher.subscribe('update-status');
        channel.bind('App\\Events\\UpdateDeviceStatus', function (data) {
            console.log(data);

                  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and realised that I just forgot to listen to the queue: `php artisan queue:listen redis`